# How to determine correct heap size for ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I determine the heap size required for 1 GB  logs having 1 day retention period?

if I take the machine with 32 GB heap size (64 GB RAM) how many GB logs I can keep in this for 1 day?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on various factors like the number of indexing requests, search requests, cache utilization, size of search and indexing requests, number of shards/segments etc, also heap size should follow the sawtooth pattern, and instead of guessing it, you should start measuring it.

**The good thing is that you can starting right, by assigning 50% of RAM as ES Heap size which is not crossing 32 GB.**